# Laravel run Artisan Command Cause 500

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-artisan, internal

## I use win10 system.

I have this code in `web.php`.

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('migrate');
});
```

when i visit `/foo` .I get this error page.
and when i run this command in cmd.It's working.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: if you do a simple echo instead of the Artisan::Call does that return the echo?

Comment: why you assign artisan command to a variable ? what is the point of this ?

Comment: How do I get PHP errors to display?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/984422

Comment: @HasanTıngır to know if the command works right(return 0).

Comment: @sari This code works right at my mac.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto still can't get errors.I think it's may caused by file permission.But i don't know how to fix it .

Comment: Can you check your error log, what gives you ? (storage/log/laravel.log)

Comment: i understand that what i was trying to get you to do is to see if your install as a whole is working. a simple echo will either give you a 500 error or work if it work then we can dig further as to what the root of the issue is. @TonyCat

Comment: @HasanTıngır It seems nothing happened to the laravel log file.

Comment: @SariYono I think it's caused by my win10 environment. Because the same code works on my mac.